# iPhone show a popup like window with user inputs

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can Some Tell me how to create a user input for the iPhone like the image below. The image shows the program asking the user for his bid. The user can also increment the bid. I can't use a popover on the iPhone since that is an iPad feature. I have tried creating a UIView but it covers the whole screen on the iPhone. I want to show a small dialog like the one in the image.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest reading the documentation first and reading a couple books on the basics of iOS development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with UIView. Just need to set the frame to an appropriate size.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(200, 300, 40, 20);
UIView *popView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

and then add the popView as the subview of the main view.